# no se como intercambiar los datos entre input

Tags: html, css, input, color

Crear un programa que pida tres colores en su caja de texto
correspondiente, en la misma pagina debe haber un botón que se llame  cambiar, al presionar dicho botón el contenido de la caja de texto 1  pasara a la caja de texto 2 y el contenido de la caja de texto 2 pasara a  la caja 3 y el contenido de la caja de texto 3 pasara a la caja de texto 1

este es mi codigo hasta ahora y lo que debo agregar segun ordenes de mi  profesor

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>trabajo 3</title>
    
 </head>
 <body>


 <form>
    Escoge un color:
 <input type="color" name="color1"> <br>
    Escoge un segundo color:
 <input type="color" name="color2"><br>
    Escoge un tercer color:
 <input type="color" name="color3"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="cambiar" value="cambiar" >
    
 </form>





 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pues a primeras guardar cada uno en variables, y luego reemplazar, pero la idea es apoyarte en tu código.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Es importante que sepas que [**aquí no hacemos tareas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320), así que debes demostrar que lo has intentado, y los errores que has tenido.